# react-testing: userEvent.click does not work

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

I'm trying to use `userEvent` for testing UI interaction. However, it does not seem to work properly. I used [this](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/intro/) document as reference. Is there some necessary setup in order for it to work?

Here's the test code:

```
  test('A', () => {
    //setup
    const user = userEvent.setup();

    const sensing = jest.fn();
    const subject = (<button onClick={sensing}>testButton</button>);

    render(subject);

    // run
    user.click(screen.getByText('testButton'));

    // check
    expect(sensing).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

Using `fireEvent.click` instead of `user.click` does work.

Part of package.json

```
"react": "^18.1.0",
"react-dom": "^18.1.0",
"@storybook/react": "^6.4.22",
"@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.9",
"@testing-library/dom": "^8.13.0",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
"@testing-library/react": "^13.2.0",
"@testing-library/react-hooks": "^8.0.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^14.2.0",

...
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`UserEvent` needs `await`. So you want to write this:

```
  test('A', async () => {
    //setup
    const user = userEvent.setup();

    const sensing = jest.fn();
    const subject = (<button onClick={sensing}>testButton</button>);

    render(subject);

    // run
    await user.click(screen.getByText('testButton'));

    // check
    expect(sensing).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

Comment: What about the right click or {button: 2} whatever? seems like not supported yet

Answer (score 2):

The mock will not be called if the button you are clicking is disabled. This function will be called by fireEvent but not by a user event.Check if the button is disabled or not